# Vba Selenium: Check if html tag is present in the source code

Tags: vba, excel, selenium, selenium-webdriver

This is my issue, I have a Vba code using selenium that loops trough a lot of urls.   I need to validate if one tag is present, and if it is I need the code to resume next, the problems is that I just started to use selenium, and I don't know how to validate if the tag is present in a given source code.

This is the tag:

```
<a class="fontdn" id="fontdn" href="#" title="Zoom Out (Key: -)">Zoom Out (Key: -)</a>
```

and this is the Vba-selenium code I have so far, this suppose to return the number of elements with this id but doesn't work.

```
If IE.findElementsByTitle("Zoom Out (Key: -)").Size() > 0 Then Exit For
```

Comment: Some lines of codes are missing here, I think ^^

Answer (score 1):

I checked the wrapper for Excel VBA, I don't see a `findElementsByTitle` in the code:  https://code.google.com/p/selenium-vba/source/browse/trunk/wrapper/WebElement.cs

You should be able to use:

```
If IE.findElementsByClassName("fontdn").Size() > 0 Then Exit For
```

**Edit**

I looked through the wrapper source some more, `findElementsByClassName` returns an array.  Excel VBA array uses `Length`, not `Size()`, from what I can tell.

Maybe this?

```
If IE.findElementsByClassName("fontdn").Length > 0 Then Exit For
```

Comment: Thank you for answering Richard, you right i was wrong but even changing IE.findElementsByClassName("fontdn").Size() > 0 is always returning more than 0 because it's exit the loop every time, To make sure i checked  the source code and there was no such "fontdn" classname, so i'm feeling hesitation about the .size property in the fact that returns the amount of tags that contains that classname.

Comment: I went around and i found the way to get it.  Thank you Richard

Comment: this is how i get it. 
TagCheck = IE.findElementByClassName("thumbs").getAttribute("id")

If TagCheck = "thumbs" Then exit for