# VBA + Selenium won't return size of objeck/element

Tags: excel, vba, selenium

I am having a very frustrating problem with selenium.

I am using VBA + Selenium and I am trying to check whether an element exists or not.

I am doing it by finding the element and checking it's size. If it is 0 it means that it is not present.

I use the following code:

```
element_size = driver.FindElementByCss("div.toto > p:nth-child(6)").Size
```

I am probably using it wrong because I get an "object doesn't support this property" error. However if I use:

```
element_size = driver.FindElementByCss("div.toto > p:nth-child(6)").Text
```

Then I get the desired text.

So what is wrong with my size code? ( I also tried .size() but I get the same error)

Thanks for your help in advance and have a nice weekend!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the plural version of `FindElement` as below:

`element_size = driver.FindElementsByCss("div.toto > p:nth-child(6)").Size`

Comment: Yep, this was the problem! Thank you very much! :)

Answer (score 1):

> I am using VBA + Selenium and I am trying to check whether an element
>   exists or not.

Try following:

```
number_of_elements = driver.FindElementsByCss("div.toto > p:nth-child(6)").Length
```

Answer is based on: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22949100/2517622

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion!

Answer (score 1):

Example 1 with FindElement:

```
Sub Script1()
    Dim drv As New Selenium.FirefoxDriver
    drv.Get "http://stackoverflow.com"

    Set ele = drv.FindElementByCss("#hlogo", raise:=False, timeout:=0)
    If Not ele Is Nothing Then
      Debug.Print "Element is present"
    End If

    drv.Quit
End Sub
```

Example 2 with IsElementPresent:

```
Private By As New Selenium.By

Sub Script2()
    Dim drv As New Selenium.FirefoxDriver
    drv.Get "http://stackoverflow.com"

    If drv.IsElementPresent(By.Css("#hlogo")) Then
      Debug.Print "Element is present"
    End If

    drv.Quit
End Sub
```

Example 3 with FindElementsByCss:

```
Sub Script3()
    Dim drv As New Selenium.FirefoxDriver
    drv.Get "http://stackoverflow.com"


    Set elts = drv.FindElementsByCss("#hlogo")
    If elts.Count > 0 Then
      Debug.Print "Element is present"
    End If

    drv.Quit
End Sub
```

To get the latest version in date working with the above examples:
https://github.com/florentbr/SeleniumBasic/releases/latest

Answer (score 1):

You should use

```
element_height = driver.FindElementByCss("div.toto > p:nth-child(6)").Size.Height
element_width = driver.FindElementByCss("div.toto > p:nth-child(6)").Size.Width
```

Size is not a numeral, but an object with two properties.

Comment: I see, you might be using a different wrapper, my solution works if you use the version from GitHub, not Google Code

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, I do this if I have nothing to do with the resident functions for testing whether an element is present or not.

```
src = driver.getHtmlSource ' I get all the source string

If Instr(src, "desired string to find") <> 0 Then 'in this case, if your desired string is caught inside the source, this is true. then do stuff below
  'do stuff 
End if
```

This works for me and helped me a lot.